# Getting historical administrative boundary GIS files for India?

Tags: shapefile, data, administrative-boundaries, india

I am currently working on a project for which I need to get GIS maps of India at a district-level in the 80's and 90's. India's district and state boundaries have changed considerably over the time period 1980-2011, and I need to map these changes over time.

Most of the versions that I found online are current (or based on the 2011 Census). Is it possible to find these older GIS files?

Comment: Since GIS became popular in the 1980s it could be that there are Shapes. If not i would try to get topographical maps, scan them and georeference them to create the Shapes by yourself. Or also try to ask the relavant (local) authorities in India.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, @Dirk, I couldn't find the shapes online, and I spoke to one Indian organisation that didn't have any of these files. I can try to use the topographical maps, possibly.

Comment: need hyd wardwise shapefile in kml format

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/168503)

Answer (score 2):

You should download the Administrative atlas from the [Census of India website](http://www.censusindia.gov.in/2011census/maps/maps2011.html)

It is PDF file, which has District (and other Administrative) boundaries for the last 150+ years.

You could Digitise the Map that you need.

Answer (score 0):

India's district shapefiles for various years back to 1987 are available here:

https://international.ipums.org/international/gis_yrspecific_2nd.shtml

Districts are almost always created by splitting existing districts, so you can create earlier districts by re-combining 2011 districts up to the "parent level" in a particular year. Information on which districts were split to create new district are available here: http://www.cdedse.org/pdf/work248.pdf